# Change FORALL to FOREACH in algorithms package

Tags: algorithms

`\FORALL` gives a "for all" loop, i would like to redefine it so that it shows "for each" instead. Any way to do that?

By the way, foreach is more often used in real programming languages than forall, is that correct?

Comment: your second question is off topic here. Better off asking it on StackOverflow?

Comment: I can't recall seeing a `forall` statement in any programming language I learned. AFAIK it would require a `foreach` in its implementation anyway, i.e. `foreach VAR in ARRAY { if (somefunc(VAR)) { do_something } }`, so it would automatically be more often used.

Comment: @Martin: But "for all" often makes more sense in pseudocode than "for each", because pseudocode often operates on sets and it's natural to write "for all x `\in` Set".

Comment: @Andrey - I prefer "for each x in S" or more commonly "for any x in S" as "for all" indicates plural form as far as I feel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple enough and covered in the [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) manual:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
```

This command redefines the macro that is used to typeset `\FORALL`. It should be placed in the document preamble.

Comment: Then I would also say `\let\FOREACH\FORALL` and use `\FOREACH` instead in the code. Maybe also change `\FORALL` to an error message afterwards. This makes the code more readable and avoids confusion.

Comment: @Martin Is there anyway I can place `\let\FOREACH\FORALL` outside the `begin{algorithmic}` section? I tried `\let\FOREACH\algorithmicforall` but it didn't work

Comment: @colinfang: I would put the `\let\FOREACH\FORALL` in the preamble after loading the package. Using `\let\FOREACH\algorithmicforall` seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Martin - if I put it after `usepackage`, it doesn't work. The only way it works is to add the setting each time the environment invokes.

Comment: @colinfang: I see, then use `\def\FOREACH{\FORALL}` instead. It is only a cosmetic change anyway.

Comment: @Martin - Great, It works at last

Comment: @MartinScharrer Make `\forall` an error.  Now you're talking.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the following trick to convert `\FOR` into `\FOREACH` in `algorithms` package

```
\FOR{\textbf{each} a in b}
\STATE do something
\ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a For Each loop in the [`algorithm2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) package.

Comment: eh, I have just got used to the algorithms package... is algorithm2e better?

Answer (score 1):

The `algorithmicx` package lets defined its own commands. In your case you could put in the preamble:

```
\algblockdefx[Foreach]{Foreach}{EndForeach}[1]{\textbf{foreach} #1 \textbf{do}}{\textbf{end foreach}}
```

which can then be used as a `For` loop:

```
\Foreach{$i \in I$}
    \State bar
    \State foo
\EndForeach
```