# Customizing the algorithm/algpseudocode package

Tags: algorithms

After asking this question: [Change FORALL to FOREACH in algorithms package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18335/2693), some issues arose in the comments.  I have created the following sample document, and have three questions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
% Need it for floating environment
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
% Hide endif .etc
\usepackage{caption}
% Need it for \caption*

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
% \algrenewcommand instead of \renewcommand according to manual
\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to}}
% Not stated in manual, \Return and \algorithmicreturn are defined, but no \algorithmicstate, why?
\newcommand{\Dosth}{\textbf{Do Something }}
% Need space here, why?
\def\ForEach{\ForAll}
% Define new macro. Fail to use \algorithmicforall, why?
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption*{\textbf{Algorithm:} \textsc{Depth First Search}} \label{alg:dfs1}

    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require Graph $\mathcal{G = (V,E)}$
        \Ensure Graph $\mathcal{G}$ with its vertices marked with consecutive integers in the order they have been visited by the DFS traversal
        \Statex
        \State Mark each vertex in $\mathcal{V}$ with $0$ \Comment As ``unvisited''
        \State $count \gets 0$
        \ForEach{vertex $v \in \mathcal{V}$}
            \If{$v$ is marked with $0$}
                \State \Call{DFS}{$v$}
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \State \Return
        \Statex
        \Function{DFS}{$v$}
            \State $count \gets count + 1$
            \State mark $v$ with $count$
            \State \Dosth with $v$
            \ForEach{vertex $w \in \mathcal{V}$ adjacent to $v$}
                \If{$w$ is marked with $0$}
                    \State \Call{DFS}{$w$}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State \Return
        \EndFunction

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

1. Why is there no `\algorithmicstate` defined?
2. Why, when I define a new command do I need to add a space after it?
3. Why does `\def\ForEach{\ForAll}` work but `\def\ForEach{\algorithmicforall}` not work

Comment: I changed your question title to something  a bit more useful, and moved your "questions in the comments" to real questions. It's not generally a good idea to ask questions in the code.  Also, it's preferable to ask individual questions, unless there is a common thread to all of them.  (In this case, that's a bit of a judgement call.)

Comment: @Alan Munn - Good, thx. And I have changed the question 3.

Comment: I've updated my answer for your new question 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions.

> Why no `\algorithmicstate`?

Perhaps an oversight by the package writer?  Perhaps never intended to exist.  Either way, you can create your own version of the command using:

```
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicstate}{\textbf{State:}}
```

> `\newcommand{\Dosth}{\textbf{Do Something }}` % Need space here, why?

This is answered here: [\newcommand and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17730/2693)

> Why does `\def\ForEach{\ForAll}` work but `\def\ForEach{\algorithmicforall}` not work?

Because `\ForAll` is a more complicated macro than `\algorithmicforall`. It is defined using the following command:

```
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]{\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
```

The `\algdef` command does a lot of things, and one of the things it does with a for loop is to set up an expectation for the end of the for, i.e. the `\EndFor`.

When you define `\ForEach` to be `ForAll`, you don't change the definition of `\ForAll` you simply cause `\ForEach` to act like `ForAll`.  But if you change `ForEach` into `\algorithmicforall` you fail to create the corresponding expectation for an end for, and the code fails when it encounters `\EndFor`.